# Delphi Firedac Scripts and Exclamation Mark

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

I experienced a strange behaviour in Firedac (Delphi 10.3.3) against Firebird 3.04. The following statement

```
insert into icds(id,title) values (55,'!M01.0;M02.6;M03.5');
```

creates a record in the database like this

```
id   title
--   -------------
55   .0;M02.6;M03.5
```

when run with the fdScript component. If I run the same script with any database IDE, the record is created correctly (same database, same Server). It is defintively related to the exclamation mark because if I replace replace '!' by '?' the record is also inserted correctly by firedac. The Database is UTF8 and the varchar field is 4096 chars, I tried smaller sizes to no avail. The exclamation mark seems to swallow the following three chars.

I did not find any documentation nor did I find parameters of the component that can cause this. Is this a (nasty) bug or is it a feature I am not aware of?

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you parameterise the INSERT statement and set the :Title parameter value to include the exclamation mark?

Comment: I will test that the next days but as I have to insert a lot of data that way this anyway wouldn't be a a solution.

Comment: "wouldn't be a a solution"  Excuse me???  Doing multiple inserts using parameters is less trouble than constructing a multiplicity of custom Insert strings.

Comment: Also, it seems from your comment that you are unaware of FireDAC's 'Array DML', which is provided precisely for repeated Insert operations and similar, see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Array_DML_(FireDAC)

Comment: The scripts Inrun are huge Databaseinserts as scripts, tested in unit tests outside the application and included into the server as resources. I usenparametrzing wherever it makes sense but here it wouldncause a big amount of additional work.

Comment: Use parameters. Or process special macro characters [this way](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Special_Character_Processing), or just disable macros if you need to write SQL command this way. It's the [substitution variable](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Substitution_Variables) which causes you this misbehavior.

Comment: use SET DEFINE OFF in script
or set Script.ScriptOptions.MacroExpand to False

Comment: Thanks, that I will try!