# Delphi FDQuery.SQL string starting with '!' dont work

Tags: delphi, firedac

I have a query that is dynamically set up with a parameter.
I query for lines with a varchar field that contains values that can begin with a '!'.
But I get no match of those.
I use SQLServer as the database server.
If I take the sqlcode and run it directly in the database manager it works but not with TFDQuery.
Se the code example below:

```
  myParameter := '!Tommy';
  with qryExec do
  begin
   SQL.Clear ;
   SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM myTable T WHERE T.Name='+quotedStr(myParameter));
   active := true ;
   first;
    if Not Eof then
    begin
      Result := True;
    end;
  end; //with
```

I have no idea what's wrong here, so I would be happy if anyone could come with an explanation.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59812774/delphi-firedac-scripts-and-exclamation-mark?

Comment: You might have a look at https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)

Comment: May be a parameters pb,  try   `ResourceOptions.ParamCreate := False `

Comment: Thanks a lot, really fast answers :). I found that Andreas and MartynA answers is about the same. I haven't tried philnext:s solution, it would probably work but I love Brians solution below. It's really simple and nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using actual parameters which also avoids the possibility of SQL injection. There are also overloaded versions of `Open` that reduce the housekeeping lines.

```
  FDQuery1.Open('SELECT * FROM myTable T WHERE T.Name= :NAME',['!Tommy'],[ftWideString]);
```